# epsilon delta definition of limit proof

Tags: functions, limits

$f(x,y)=\frac{xy^3}{x^2 + 4y^2}$,

$(x,y)$ not eaqual to $(0,0)$;

use $\epsilon-\delta$ definition to show that $f(x,y)$ tends to $(0,0)$.

I'm unsure how to deal with fractions for, $\epsilon-\delta$ proof... could applying the proof separately for numerator and denominator; then later combining them help?

Comment: can you at least make the title more descriptive, there are a infinite number of limit proofs one could do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb x^2 +  4y^2\geq 4xy$ applying AM $\geq$ GM then $ f(x.y) \leq \frac{y^2}{4} $ from there you can get the  $\epsilon-\delta $ proof

Comment: so i essentially apply epsilon-delta to y^2/4. meaning the answer is delta< (4*epsilon)^0.5

Comment: oh and...is AM = arithmetic mean, and GM = geometric mean. Also your initial equation doesn't really remind me of how it links to AM or GM.

Comment: yes AM = arithmetic mean, and GM = geometric mean from this (a+b)/2 >= sqrt(ab) take a=x^2 (>=0) and b= 4y^2(>=0)